# convert column data varchar to timestamp in H2 Database

Tags: h2

I wanted to convert varchar data into timestamp in existing table. And also change datatype of table.

```
DB: H2
platform: Windows
```

Comment: What does your current var char look like? Is it a var char in unit seconds? Is it a unix date? Is it a time stamp?

Comment: Its varchar in timestamp like below
7-18-2020 7:51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your timestamp is not in SQL or ISO format, so you can't simply change data type of a column. Automatic conversion is not possible in your case.

In 1.4.200 and older versions you need to perform two steps:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(V VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('7-18-2020 7:51');

UPDATE TEST SET V = PARSEDATETIME(V, 'M-d-yyyy HH:mm');
ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN V SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP;
```

`PARSEDATETIME` returns a `TIMESTAMP` value, but here it is assigned back to `VARCHAR` column, this operation cause an implicit cast using SQL format (`'2020-07-18 07:51:00'`) that can be converted back to `TIMESTAMP` automatically during the following change of data type of the column.

In H2 2.0.202 and newer versions there is a simpler one-step solution:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(V VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('7-18-2020 7:51');

ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN V
    SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP USING PARSEDATETIME(V, 'M-d-yyyy HH:mm');
```

Comment: Does he need to add a intermediate from (M-d-yy HH:mm) to (MM-dd-yy HH:mm)?

Comment: Single-character `M` and `d` are able to accept months and days with both one and two digits. Actually it there are no constraints on column, it should be possible to simplify the conversion procedure, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenijRyazanov for you reply. It worked.

But if my date format is 17Mar2020145558. The PARSEDATETIME(V, 'ddmmyyyyHHmmss') function doesn't worked.

Can you help here please :)

Comment: It worked with:

PARSEDATETIME(V, 'ddMMMyyyyHHmmss')

Cheers!!!

Comment: with com.h2database v2.0.206 USING works also for simpler casts for e.g. VARCHAR -> INT (for H2 and PostgreSQL the same way): ALTER TABLE mytable  ALTER COLUMN myfield TYPE INTEGER USING (myfield::INTEGER);